# Ajax Loading and Adsense Mobile Ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, adsense

JQuery mobile and Adsense mobile ads don't mix together. When I try to post an adsense mobile ad on a webpage with JQuery Mobile the ad loads on top of all the other content.

Is there any way around this? What about other mobile frameworks?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the page directly in Firefox (or $insert_preferred_browser)?

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this code?

Comment: Have you checked if the database-connection is available?

Comment: Yes I'm connected to the database. Jquery Mobile returns undefined. And I'm about to try it in fire fox now...

Comment: `Doesn't seem to be working` neither are your problem-specification skills!

Comment: Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy cow that's ugly. have you considered something as simple as:

```
switch($Date) {
   case 'today':         $diff = 0; break;
   case 'yesterday':     $diff = 1; break;
   case 'lastsevendays': $diff = 7; break;
   default:              $diff = 0;
}

$sql = "SELECT .... WHERE date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $diff DAY);";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the `or die()` portion. You're not checking for query errors and assume everything worked fine.

As well, note that MySQL's date format is YYYY-MM-DD. you're generating d-m-Y, which is exactly backwards, so most likely your problem is from passing in invalid dates.